# React Native: how to run flipper with apple silicon

Tags: react-native, apple-m1, flipper

I have a problem trying to run an application made in react-native which uses Flipper in apple silicon, I get the following error:

[image]

I tried some things like running Xcode in rosetta mode but it didn't work, I also tried some possible solutions mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28419), but none of the options worked.

for now, the only thing that has worked is to adjust the `react-native.config.js` file to prevent auto-linking for Flipper, like so:

```js
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-flipper': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
  //... other react native configs
};
```

This option disables Flipper and what I need is to make it work, not to disable it.

Comment: I have a problem with this approach, some team members have computers with M1 processors and others with Intel, if I make this change would it still work for both?

Answer (score 1):

I am using flipper universal builds from here:

https://github.com/chiragramani/FlipperReleases/releases

As a note, I am using this for quite some time and once the new version gets out you might need to wait for 2-3 days until it generates a new universal build there.
If you don't want to wait then you can clone the repo and run the script file and it will generate a new build instantly.

For more details you all can check this thread: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/pull/3553

Answer (score -1):

> Bump the FLIPPER_VERSION variable in android/gradle.properties. as

```
# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.158.0
```

> Then run `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`

It will integrate **flipper** on your project. By using this you need to install flipper to debug an app on your system and then install **Sdk** on the flipper app. then you can debug your app by using the flipper.

For further explanation, you can visit [Here](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Did u mean 0.58.0 version is supported for apple silicon? I think this does not shed any light on the problem mentioned.

Comment: No! I was not saying this. If you see I recommend using the 0.158.0 version, And when you run that given command that automatically links all files and created a file of "ReactNativeFilter.java". By using this you can setup flipper on your project.

Comment: I did some tests and the proposed solution does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below steps:

1. Clean everything, use everything based on the M1 build, I mean Xcode, packages, libraries and etc. everything must be based on the M1 build form
2. Initial an RN project, go to the ios folder, and run this command: `arch -x86_64 pod install`.
3. It wouldn't affect your project development source and an Intel base macOS system or other platforms would be able to continue on this source.

Comment: When u say "clean everything" do you mean remove pods and re-install them? or you can post a step-by-step of what you call cleaning? I removed the pods and then did step 2 and it didn't work, it keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: Exactly, clean the latest builds, pod files and etc.

Comment: I followed the steps indicated in the answer and I still get the same result, error due to the architecture.